# Error while inserting through odbc driver

Tags: java, odbc

What can be possibly wrong in the following statement trying to insert into ms accses

```
   insert into mytable("Submission","Applicants Email", 
              "Applicants - 1") 
   values("abc school district","stger@ers.net",
              "Incomplete")
```

While trying to execute through java odbc driver . i am getting:

```
         java.sql.SQLException: [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Invalid bracketing of name '[stger@ers.net]'.
```

Comment: Format the query in readable form..

Comment: That exception is caused by the ODBC reformatting your query before sending it, but I'm not sure what you can do to fix it.  It appears to be caused by the @ symbol though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In access values need to be in single quotes , it seems , here is what worked for me

Thanks everyone for your time.

Comment: 6 years later - this saved my life.